# Update Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 13.04 without losing dual boot

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows

This is my first question and i hope that some one could help please. 
So i have a dell laptop given by my school, with grub dual boot. I have windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I would like to know if i update ubuntu from the manager will i lose the windows boot ? how could i do just to update it without touching the windows OS neither the grub.

Thank you very much for your help ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system currently running is changing the grub.cfg already whenever there is a kernel update and installing grub again won't break anything with the windows dualboot. This means if you didn't change grub manually, in which case you wouldn't ask this question, you can safely install any new Ubuntu you like without breaking anything (except for maybe a newer ubuntu version being broken by itself).

I really advise you to not do upgrades but do a fresh install as this really helps minimising possible problems. I myself had a really broken and unstable system after upgrading from 12.10 to 13.04. I can't imagine how much worse it may be if you upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 to 13.04.

If you want to wait for it, the next LTS release will be in april 2014.

Answer (score 1):

If you update Ubuntu from the update manager, all your grub settings should stay put.  It has worked for me numerous times with no problem.

You will notice that to upgrade from 12.04 to 13.04 actually requires two upgrades [upon the documentations](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes): first from 12.04 to 12.10, then from 12.10 to 13.04.

> To avoid damaging your running system, upgrading should only be done **from one release to the next release** (e.g. Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 12.10) or from one LTS release to the next (e.g. Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS).

Comment: is it ok if i update from 12.04 LTS to 12.10 or should i wait for an LTS release ?